# Apple Watch Complication Template - Modular small image multicolor

Tags: apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

Hello,

I'm trying to create a complication for Apple Watch, in the `modularSmall` family, using a `CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage`. I want the image to be displayed as a multicolor image when the tint is set to "multicolor" (just like the calculator's complication). My issue is that it is always displayed as a white image, and never as a multicolor image. I tried to set the `tintColor` of both the image provider and the template to `.none` and other various values, but I can't get my full color image when scrolling trough the templates... My code is as follow :

```swift
case .modularSmall:
            let imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: UIImage(named: "Complication/Modular")!)
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage(imageProvider: imageProvider)
            handler(template)
```

Any idea to help ?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Also for the small circular image template too.  I also haven't found a solution.  It seems that because it uses a onePieceImage, it has to be shades of white, but I don't know another way to code it.